I can't write code for a telegram bot on node js so that it works correctly
I want to make it so that when I press the keyboard next to the text input field, the bot sends inline_keyboard, but I can't, if I try to write the code, then when I press /menu, it sends the message 'Bot menu' several times and increases by one, help me solve the problem
bot.onText(/\/menu/, (msg) => {
   bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Bot menu", mainKeyboard);
});

const mainKeyboard = {

  reply_markup: { 

   keyboard: [
   [{text:'⭐️ chapter1', callback_data:'section1'}],
   [{text:'⭐️ chapter2', callback_data:'section2'}],
   [{text:'⭐️ chapter3', callback_data:'section3'}],
     ]
   }
}

bot.on('message', (msg) => {
   const chatId = msg.chat.id
   const text = msg.text

   if (text === '⭐️ chapter1') {
       const section1Keyboard = {
           reply_markup: {
               inline_keyboard: [
                   [{ text: 'subsection 1.1', callback_data: 'subsection1_1' }],
                   [{ text: 'subsection 1.2', callback_data: 'subsection1_2' }],
                   [{ text: 'Назад', callback_data: 'back' }],
               ],
           },
       }
       bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'you have chosen chapter 1', section1Keyboard);
   } else if (text === '⭐️ chapter2') {
       bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'you have chosen chapter 2');
   } else if (text === '⭐️ chapter3') {
       bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'you have chosen chapter 3');
   }
})

I'm just trying to make bots, I don't know what can be done in this situation, I'm starting to doubt that it is possible to connect a keyboard and inline_keyboard
